# calculation using formula in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working with Humidity calculator where I have to do one equation that is:

```
e  = 6.1078 * 10 ** ((TD * A)/(TD + B));
```

but its not working. Any ideas why?

Comment: any error log or specific information on why it isnt working

Comment: I'd suggest firstly splitting the formula up into its components, and then assigning variables with each part. This way you can see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by the "**" operator you mean the exponential operator. In that case you might want to use the function exp() with the proper corrections (exp() uses the natural number as its base).

Comment: Yep.  The `**` operator means exponentiation, because `^` in CS means "exclusive or"

Answer (score 0):

Why there is 2 *s in that equation?

```
e = 6.1078 * 10 * ((TD * A)/(TD + B));
```

This should work. Also , considering TD and B, (TD + B) should not be zero.

Comment: Its need 2 *s frnd that is real formula

Comment: What are e, A, B and TD? double or int? Do u have values assigned to those variables?

Comment: If I add this statement with 2 *s in Xcode, it gives me compile time error.. How it could be possible for u to compile?

Comment: I have looked at this [link](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/meteorology/temp-dewpoint/). Definitely there must be some exponentials involved.